# CSS acting jumpy when loading a page in Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Every time I open a link in my rails app deployed on Heroku, it shows the visited page with absolutely no CSS before returning to normal view. Sometimes it acts jumpy and keeps changing between no-CSS and CSS view. This happens for like the first 1-2 seconds of visiting a link, and this happens for every link I visit within the app. Everything looks and works fine locally, though. Below are extracts from `application.html.haml` and `application.css.scss` in case they might be useful:

**application.html.haml**

```
%head
  %title
  %meta{:content => "IE=edge", "http-equiv" => "X-UA-Compatible"}/
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, 'data-turbolinks-eval': false
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  = csrf_meta_tags
  %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1", :name => "viewport"}/
```

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require 'masonry/transitions'
*= require font-awesome
*= require jasny-bootstrap.min
*/
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/368041/why-do-webpages-sometimes-appear-as-plain-html-before-a-refresh) on SuperUser. I'm assuming it works just fine when running it locally? You could also try using the [network throttling features](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/network-conditions?hl=en) in Chrome.

Comment: @nicholas79171 So I noticed a few things in the Network tab of chrome dev tools. It appears that the css file is loading after the rest of the page loads upon initial visit. Upon revisit, the same css file loads _twice_. Could it have something to do with turbolinks? Because everything loads fine when I do a full page refresh. And yes, everything works fine locally.

Comment: **Update:** I've run both `rake assets:clobber` and `heroku run rake assets:clobber` to no avail; the css file still loads twice upon revisiting a link. So I'm assuming it's not loading twice because of asset precompilation since `public/assets` doesn't exist. The **Size** column in the Network tab shows `(from cache)` for both the css files, if that's of any help